# How fetch sms based on number saved in internal DB

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have a small query. How to fetch the SMS of only particular mobile numbers that is stored in internal Data base.? this is the below code i have tried but i can get only one number

```
for (Contact_pojo contpojo: smslist) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            SMS_Adapter sms_adapter = new SMS_Adapter();
            if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).equals("+91"+contpojo.getContactnumber())){
                sms_adapter.setSmsname(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                sms_adapter.setSmsaddress(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
                smsadapter.add(sms_adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SMS_Adapter sms_adapter = new SMS_Adapter();
for (Contact_pojo contpojo: smslist) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("+91"+contpojo.getContactnumber())){
                sms_adapter.setSmsname(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                sms_adapter.setSmsaddress(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
                smsadapter.add(sms_adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

you can use `contains` method instead of `equals`

Comment: there is no change i am getting only first one